# Weblogic 10.3.5 Admin console Deployment page - Missing status of applications

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I have an instance of Weblogic 10.3.5 running with a bunch of apps.

For some reason, the deployments page in the Admin console stopped showing the health (status) of the deployed apps (usually a green check icon). Just looks weird. Any ideas on how I can bring that back?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The apps are not running, possibly because their target machine isn't currently up.  Find out what managed server they are targeted to and make sure it's running.  If you want them to run on the Admin Server, you can change their targets via configuration.

Comment: Found that the startup up script of the managed server isn't pointing to the AdminServer making the deployments status inactive. Fixed it and they are all showing up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

some times it may happen...

First you have to make sure all the applications are running properly or not....

If any issues in deploying application or deployed application then it may show in this manner....

Exact solution to your problem is Restarting admin node

But it is better to do following steps...

1. Stop both admin and Managed nodes.
2. Start the Admin node then managed node.

Check the console...